# What is probability that students will be evenly divided among the 3 categories? What is the marginal probability that 2 will be in the middle half?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Problem:

The campus recruiter for an international conglomerate classifies the large number of students she interviews into three categories - the lower quarter, the middle half, and the upper quarter. If she meets six students on a given morning, what is the probability that they will be evenly divided among the three categories? What is the marginal probability that exactly two will belong to the middle half?

attempt:

probability that they will be evenly divided among the three categories = (2/6)*(2/6)*(2/6) = 1/27

the marginal probability that exactly two will belong to the middle half = 2/6 = 1/3 .

Can someone please help me? I am not sure how to do this. Any feedback would really help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose she meets people in sequence. Write L for lower, M for middle, and U for upper. Her classifications can be thought of as a word of length $6$ over the alphabet L, M, U.

We find the probability of LLMMUU. This word means that the first person fell in the lower category, as did the next  one. Then came two middles, and then two uppers. The probability of this is $(1/4)(1/4)(1/2)(1/2)(1/4)(1/4)$.

This turns out to be the probability of *any particular word* with two L, two M, and two U. We count how many such words there are.

The $2$ L's can be placed in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, and for each of these ways the $2$ M's can be placed in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, for a total of $90$. TThus our required probability is
$$(90)(1/4)(1/4)(1/2)(1/2)(1/4)(1/4).$$

We leave the second problem to you. Similar ideas are involved. One can save effort by thinking of the classificaction as middle (M) and non-middle (N). Note that $M$ and $N$ each have probability $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It really helps. For the marginal probability. I am thinking it is of the form binomial. With n =6 and p = 1/2 or 0.5 Then it will be $\binom{6}{2}$(0.5)^2(1-0.5)^4

Comment: You are welcome. That's right, it is just like tossing a fair coin $6$ times and asking for the probability of exactly $2$ heads.